# How can I configure npm-gyp on Windows to use gcc instead of VC++?

Tags: windows, node.js, gcc, npm

Is there a way to configure npm-gyp to use gcc (as it appears to on Linux) on a Windows box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as described [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/402).

**UPDATE**
An [enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/issues/detail?id=448) has been submitted to the gyp team.
**UPDATE**
...but probably won't be acted upon. [[comment]](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/issues/detail?id=448#c1)